# IE cross browser compatibility problem

Tags: html, css

i have a problem in using IE. Everthing is good in using firefox but IE 6 seems to be creating more trouble for css. so i used

```
<![if !IE]>
<link href="ie6.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]>
```

To fix a problem but it doesnot work. Anything wrong in this code? Because when i altered this css nothing has changed in IE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, your [conditional comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx) says "if **not** IE".
Also note that you're using a *downlevel-revealed* conditional comment, which means every browser (*except* IE) will include the extra CSS file.

Use `<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->` instead.

Comment: @Jay Update your question with more of the code you used, because this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this condition statement:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <link href="ie6.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
```

Basically its saying if the browser is less than IE7 then use this style sheet. Works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]><link href="ie6.css" rel="stylesheet"><![endif]-->
```

Comment: Though your answer is technically correct, I wouldn't test for `lte IE 6`; IE <= 5.5 has many other quirks to deal with, as IE 6 Standards Mode differs very much from IE 5.5's rendering engine, also known as Quirks Mode in IE >= 6.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this;

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
this place for your stuff.
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<![if !IE]>      ! means not IE there
```

To:

```
<![if IE]>        means if it is IE
```

to  use IE-based CSS.

Comment: Not correct: you're still using [downlevel-revealed conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx#dlrevealed), like the OP did; every other browser than IE won't recognize these things as valid HTML and will simply ignore them, so everything inside will not be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Is the ie.css placed after any other css files? If you have placed it before your regular css it will be overridden.
It should look something like this:

```
 <link href="other.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <![if IE]>
     <link href="ie6.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <![endif]>
```