# css - 100% + padding?

Tags: css

As most people know,

a 100% div with a 5px padding is actually 100% + 10px wide.

One obvious solution to this is to [wrap the child div in a wrapper that has a 10px margin](http://jsfiddle.net/EMYBm/)
however this method requires you to add extra markup, I am looking for a way to do 100%+padding without the extra div.

any ideas?

Comment: if you use `padding-left` and `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`? this is that the result you want? or you can look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219175/width-100-padding

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Block elements like `<div>`s automatically assume a 100% width *after padding*. I.e. you should be able to achieve the desired effect simply by specifying a padding, leaving the width on `auto` and making sure the element has `display: block` (default for `<div>`).

http://jsfiddle.net/EMYBm/8/

Comment: Well, ok, bad example on my part, lets assume its not a div, instead it is an html input...

Comment: @Hailwood That's quite an important detail to omit. :-P In that case you have little choice but to use a wrapper (if you care about IE).

Answer (score 12):

You should look into the `box-sizing` CSS property...

- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing

I put together an example to show you how this works and the difference between having the `box-sizing` property and not having it. Check out the fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/bKsad/2/

Note that this won't work in IE7 or below :/

I hope this helps.
Hristo

Comment: or not :) my recommendation is to use `box-sizing` for everything besides IE7 and below but for IE7 and below, use conditional stylesheets with the extra markup. for more info on conditional stylesheets, check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/3193435/196921

Comment: out of curiosity, if you can do conditional stylesheets, you could technically do conditional markup, but, is this any more efficient than actually just using the un-styled markup?